# WP Backend: Create custom menu for specific User Group

Tags: wordpress

I am using **Members** plugin to manage **User Groups** (restrict pages/posts for specific user group) now to show the links to that user group in back-end I need a plugin for creating **Custom Menu** where the **allowed pages/posts** links will be shown (back-end) for the specific **user group**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what I do is to add this script in my theme's `function.php`

```
// Admin bar menu w.r.t role
function wp_admin_bar_new_item() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    if (current_user_can('contractor')){

        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
            'id' => 'wp-admin-bar-new-item',
            'title' => __('Contractor Menu'),
            'href' => 'http://my_site/contractor/'
        ));

    } elseif (current_user_can('consultant')) {

        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
            'id' => 'wp-admin-bar-new-item',
            'title' => __('Consultant Menu'),
            'href' => 'http://my_site/consultant/'
        ));
    }
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wp_admin_bar_new_item');
```

and fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, dont know exatly which plugin or code would solve your problem.
But here are some resources:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Resources
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/capability